# How to troubleshoot CRM 2011 required field issues.

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have been setting some fields in standard forms as required, simple stuff, point and click. For the most part they work fine. But every once and a while they allow a user to fill in the form (say a case) and not fill in one or some of the required fields. This is happening for the same users so I know its not a rights issue. I have nothing setup programmably.

I am thinking it has something to do with them working very quickly with CRM 2011 (its an on-prem version and they all have IE 11 and the servers are running rollup 15)

because they also seem to have to restart IE 11 every once and while throughout the day as well. Is anyone else getting this or has come across this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have also faced this issue sometimes with CRM 2011 On-Premise. This happened sometimes with Phonecall activity form when user filled and saved the form without filling few fields which were marked as mandatory. I believe this happens when CRM server performs very slow.

Comment: I have never seen it on any of our deployments, however we don't have any users using IE11. We currently have UR11 and UR16 onpremise setups. IE11 isn't currently supported in CRM 2011 so quite possibly is some oddity with that.

Answer (score 1):

AS i know, IE11 isn't currently supported in CRM 2011. We use IE9 with rollup 15 and IE10 in compatibility mode with some issues.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2935509
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784954

Comment: you are right, IE11 can be the reason for the issues

Comment: The reason that we went to IE 11 was for the spell check in French and English for the users within the browser because they send a lot of emails from the web based CRM. They do not use the outlook plugin because the client did not want the from address to be from the user, they wanted it all to come from orders@sample.com is there a better way to have the spell check for emails and maybe I down grade them to IE 10 to possibly resolve this issue?